# How to call function after $ionicPlatform.ready in karma jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, jasmine

Can someone explain how do I expect a call after an $ionicPlatform.ready in my jasmine tests ?

Here a simple sample of code of my controller:

```
function myController($ionicPlatform, myService) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        myService
        .get()
        .then(function() {
            // success
        })
        .catch(function() {
            // error
        });
    });
}
```

Here is the test :

```
function myControllerTest() {
    var $controller,
        $ionicPlatform,
        $q,
        $rootScope,
        controller,
        deferred,
        myServiceMock;

    beforeEach(module('my_module'));
    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$ionicPlatform_, _$q_, _$rootScope_) {
        $controller = _$controller_;
        $ionicPlatform = _$ionicPlatform_;
        $q = _$q_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        deffered = $q.defer();
        myServiceMock = {
            'get': jasmine.createSpy('myService.get').and.returnValue(deferred.promise)
        };

        spyOn($ionicPlatform, 'ready').and.callThrough();

        controller = $controller('myController', {
            '$ionicPlatform': $ionicPlatform,
            'myService': myServiceMock
        });
    }));

    it('should call myService.get after $ionicPlatform.ready is fired', function() {
        expect($ionicPlatform.ready).toHaveBeenCalled(); 
        // ---> [OK]

        expect(myServiceMock.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
        // ---> [ERROR] Expected spy myService.get to have been called
    });
}
```

I hope I have been clear, and someone will be able to help me. I can't find any good documentation on this.

Best regards.